# Why does rm not remove directories?

Tags: linux, unix, rm

To delete directories you need to use the command `rmdir` instead of `rm`. I learned that unix sees everything as a file. So what is the reason that `rm` can't delete any type of file?

Answer (score 2):

Why you shouldn't remove a directory 'as if it were a file' if it's not empty seems rather obvious: then the files in that directory would not have a valid path anymore. This explains why you need either to delete recursively (`-r`) or check that the directory is empty before deleting (`rmdir`, or, in some branches of Unix, `rm -d`).

According to Wikipedia, citing [Unix 8 rm man page](http://man.cat-v.org/unix_8th/1/rm), in some old versions of Unix, the `rm` command would delete directories if they were empty, so this is more a choice of user interaction of some Unix versions than a requirement.